# Python complains SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that one, but I'm not trying to access any SQLite object in any other thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

A file that gets imported has this code in it that runs on import.

```py
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

In an unrelated file (but still part of the same package), I use this code.

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=_play)
t.start()
```

That is the only creation of another thread that I do, and `_play` simply plays a sound file. It does not have any references to SQLite.

The error I receive is the following.

`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.`

Why might I be receiving such an error?

Comment: Please create a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why such a thing happens, but the `playsound` module is the problem here. I switched to `simpleaudio` and did not have this issue anymore.

Comment: Without a reproducible question and explanation this answer is not going to be helpful.